# Override virtual function with different return type

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I understand that virtual functions can be overridden using return type if the return type is covariant.

But can we use the changed return type? or the return type will implicitly be converted to base class' function's return type like `B*` to `A*` here.

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual A *func()
    {
        A *obj=0;
        return obj;
    }
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
    virtual B *func()
    {
       B *obj =0;
       return obj;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *obj = new B();
    obj->func();              // does in fact call B::func()
    B *obj2 = obj->func();    // throws error: invalid conversion from 'A*' to 'B*'

    return 0;
}
```

It seems `obj->func()` is returning `A*` and not `B*` and hence i get this conversion error.

Comment: You can't have overridden functions with different return types. You have to use other solutions instead (like templates or (in this case) downcasting).

Comment: If `obj` can be accessed through an `A*`, why can't `obj2`? Why do you need the static type to match the dynamic type? (ignoring that you are returning a null pointer in both cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static type checking must still hold, even if the dynamic type does something slightly different in the implementation. So it really depends on the static type of the object being pointed at. When you call the virtual member on an `A*`, the return type is specified as `A*`.

If you were to call it on a `B*`, the return type of the function would have been (statically) a `B*`.

```
B *obj = new B();
obj->func();              
B *obj2 = obj->func();   // Okay now
```

Whenever you deal with run-time polynorphism in C++, it's the **static type** of the objects that determines the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Static type of `obj` is `A*` so `obj->func()` would use `A *A::func()` declaration:

- return type (`A*`)
- access specifier (`public:`)
- default argument (n/a)

Dynamic type is `B*`, so it will call `B* B::func()` and thanks to covariant type would in fact convert its return value in `A*`.

Comment: There's a third bullet, access specifiers (also N/A).

Comment: Scalars do not have "dynamic type", only class objects do. Pointers are scalars.

Answer (score 0):

Types in an inheritance hierarchy can implicitly be downcasted, in your example from `B` to `A`, and this allows for covariant return types, too. But you try to implicitly upcast,

```
B *obj2 = obj->func();
```

which cannot work because `obj` is an `A` instance, and `func()` is statically bound to the signature that `A` provides. If it's essential to get a `B*` from `A::func()` you can go with an explicit cast

```
auto *obj2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj->func());
```

but that's kind of a bad pattern, as it compromises the whole point of polymorphism.

Comment: Or even `auto *obj2 = dynamic_cast<B&>(*obj).func();`

Comment: Right. Is one version preferable? I don't see any reasons to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Depends of how you want to handle future type/modification: as changing dynamic type of `obj`  `B* C::func() override` or changing implementation of `B` `C* B::func() override`.